# pull a ssh results to variable

Tags: linux, ssh

if I ssh to another linux env, and run a command that gives me a result, can I grab that ssh result and store it locally? I have a ksh script that run locally on one linux box right now, but I need to get some parameters from another linux box into that script.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, ssh is a command just like any other, but this will be trickier if you want to ssh interactively and do it, but this could work:

```
var=$(ssh user@host command_with_output)
```

then $var will show the output of `command_with_output`

All this works best if ssh doesn't require a password as well

Comment: Password prompting all goes through to the TTY device, so is out-of-band from any content redirected here. Not that using RSA authentication isn't the best practice, but redirection doesn't make using passwords easier or harder than it would be if your script were running the command but not capturing output.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sure, it's not required to avoid a password prompt, but if you're trying to store it in a variable I assume it's in a script, and so interactive stuff is likely to be a pain.  Thanks for the clarification though.

Comment: can you just SSH to the remote server using your current login info without having to retype it via the ssh command?

Comment: @user2061886 that doesn't happen automatically, but what one usually does is to generate ssh keys (see `ssh-keygen` for that) then either copying the public key directly or using `ssh-copy-id` to do it for you.  From then on you will not need to enter a password because your private key will authenticate you to the remote server.  If you want to be able to login as a different user or have different keys for different sites you can `man ssh_config` to see how to do that